# SelectOneMenu error this.preShowValue is undefined

Tags: primefaces

Sometimes I have a problem in selectonemenu, when I click to select a value this error appears in firefox console.

TypeError: this.preShowValue is undefined[Conocer más] components.js.jsf:19:5866

my code looks like

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">

    <h:form id="frmOne">
        <ui:include src="/pages/header.xhtml" />

        <!-- other components -->

        <p:outputPanel id="selectExample">
            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-5 ">
                    <div class="ui-g ">
                        <p:outputLabel 
                            value="${etiqueta['selectLabel']}"
                            for="somExample" />

                        <p:selectOneMenu id="somExample" name="somExample"
                            value="#{selectController.selectedValue}"
                            required="true" converter="selectConverter"
                            requiredMessage="${mensaje['mandatoryInput']}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" value="#{null}" />
                            <f:selectItems
                                value="#{selectController.selectValues}"
                                var="selectOption" itemValue="#{selectOption}"
                                itemLabel="#{selectOption.name}" />
                            <p:ajax event="change"
                                listener="#{selectController.selectValueChanged()}"
                                process="@this" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:message for="somExample" id="msgSomExample"></p:message>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </p:outputPanel>

        <!-- other components -->

        <ui:include src="/pages/dialogs/_dialogs.xhtml" />

    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

The _dialogs.xhtml looks like:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">

    <p:dialog header="Dialog"
        appendToBody="true" responsive="true"
        widgetVar="dlgDialogOne" modal="true" closable="false"
         width="400">

        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-12">
                <h:outputLabel
                    value="Message" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-12 centrado-texto">
                <p:commandButton value="Yes"
                    update="frmOne"
                    onclick="PF('dlgDialogOne').hide();" process="@this"
                    action="#{selectController.dialogOk()}" />
                <p:spacer styleClass="spaceBetweenButtons" />
                <p:commandButton value="No"
                    onclick="PF('dlgDialogOne').hide();" process="@this"
                    action="#{selectController.dialogNo()}"
                    update="frmOne" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </p:dialog>

</ui:composition>
```

I'm using Primefaces 6.2 and Jboss EAP7
In firefox the error appears one time in 15 tests
In chrome the error appears one time in 22 tests

Thanks for your help

Comment: What if you don't use the dialog? Does it happen then? And is it **always** 1 in 22 and 1 in 15? Reproducable?

Comment: The selectOneMenu does not worked in firefox until for tests I comment the dialog then I put  <ui:include src="/pages/dialogs/_dialogs.xhtml" /> at the end and the selectonemenu works but sometimes there is the error I post.

Comment: If things 'sometimes' happen with different behaviour of browsers it is very difficult to help with. And ypur comment makes the question even harder to understand wothout [mcve]. Sorry. Never seen this behaviour, so it might be timing related

Comment: Yes, 'sometimes' is very difficult to know the issue, there is no changes in code and when the when the error appears is variable I was tailing the error in firefox console and there is no more information about the error, so I'm trying to be more specific as possible